# Z3 tactic for conjunction elimination in formulas with quantifiers

Tags: z3

Is there a Z3 tactic that rewrites the goal (say, one assertion with quantifiers and uninterpreted functions) into a set of conjunction-free formulas? For example, the following formula:

```
(declare-fun P (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun Q (Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun R (Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! 
  (or 
    (P x) 
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (! 
      (and 
        (Q x y) 
        (R x y)) 
     :pattern ((Q x y)) )) ) 
 :pattern ((P x)))))
```

Should be rewritten to

```
(declare-fun P (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun Q (Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun R (Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! 
  (or 
    (P x) 
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (! 
      (Q x y) 
     :pattern ((Q x y))))) 
 :pattern ((P x)))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! 
  (or 
    (P x) 
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (! 
      (R x y) 
     :pattern ((Q x y))))) 
 :pattern ((P x)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a list of tactics via `(help-tactic)`. Searching for "conjunction" yields a few hits, including tactic `simplify` with option `elim_and`, which removes all conjunctions from your example.

Rewriting the quantifiers is a different matter. I've tried a few tactics that sound potentially related, but none had any useful effects.

```
; (help-tactic)

(declare-fun P (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun Q (Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun R (Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! 
  (or 
    (P x) 
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (! 
      (and 
        (Q x y) 
        (R x y)) 
     :pattern ((Q x y)) )) ) 
 :pattern ((P x)))))

; (apply (try-for qe-light 5000)) ; no effect
; (apply (try-for qe_rec 5000)) ; appears to fail
; (apply (try-for qe2 5000)) ; appears to fail
 
(apply
  (then
    distribute-forall ; no effect
    (using-params simplify :elim_and true)
))
;;; RESULT:
; (forall ((x Int))
  ; (! (let ((a!1 (forall ((x!1 Int) (y Int))
    ; (! (not (or (not (Q x!1 y)) (not (R x!1 y))))
    ; :pattern ((Q x!1 y))))))
 ; (or (P x) a!1))
 ; :pattern ((P x))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've also tried several tactics and options but I couldn't get Z3 to split this quantifier so far.